# Addition Columns from SQL Group By Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to aggregate data linked through 4 tables and return the last linked row based up a time stamp entry in the first table for each room which is contained in the last table.

When I used the following query, I get the entries prioritized and grouped as needed:

```
SELECT 
    RoomName,
    CRV_SignalLog.SignalID,
    Max(LogTimeStamp) As LogTime
FROM 
    [CRV_SignalLog]
    inner Join [CRV_SymbolSignals]
        on CRV_SignalLog.SignalID = CRV_SymbolSignals.SignalID
    inner Join [CRV_Symbols]
        on CRV_SymbolSignals.SymbolID = CRV_Symbols.SymbolID
    inner Join [CRV_Rooms]
        on CRV_Symbols.RoomID = CRV_Rooms.RoomID
Where 
    AttributeID = 'Display_Power'
Group By 
    RoomName, 
    CRV_SignalLog.SignalID
Order By 
    LogTime Desc
```

I get a list of all rooms with the last LogTime entry for each room.  But I need to add another field from the CRV_SignalLog table to know the current state of that signal.

I have been researching and based upon other answers, I thought that I could join these results with the CRV_SignalLog table to add other columns from that table like so:

```
SELECT
    RoomName,
    DigitalValue,
    LastEntry.LogTime
From
    (SELECT 
        RoomName,
        CRV_SignalLog.SignalID,
        Max(LogTimeStamp) as LogTime
    FROM 
        [CRV_SignalLog]
        inner Join [CRV_SymbolSignals]
            on CRV_SignalLog.SignalID = CRV_SymbolSignals.SignalID
        inner Join [CRV_Symbols]
            on CRV_SymbolSignals.SymbolID = CRV_Symbols.SymbolID
        inner Join [CRV_Rooms]
            on CRV_Symbols.RoomID = CRV_Rooms.RoomID
    where 
        AttributeID = 'Display_Power'
    Group By 
        RoomName, 
        CRV_SignalLog.SignalID
    ) LastEntry
    Inner Join CRV_SignalLog 
        on CRV_SignalLog.SignalID = LastEntry.SignalID 
Order By 
    RoomName
```

But, unfortunately, that blows up the results - I think returning a row for every matching 'AttributeID = 'Display_Power' but displaying the time stamp of the last entry per room.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you want to add RoomName to your final JOIN condition?

Comment: That might work, but since RoomName is in the last table, wouldn't I have to rejoin through all 4 tables again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you are getting a result for every row in CRV_SignalLog that matches a result from your sub query by the SignalID fields. In other words, it is doing join between the LastEntry and CRV_SignalLog after the Group By is applied in the sub query.

I would try adding another join criteria between the CRV_SignalLog.LogTimeStamp and LastEntry.LogTime fields like this:

```
SELECT
    RoomName,
    DigitalValue,
    LastEntry.LogTime
From
    (SELECT 
        RoomName,
        CRV_SignalLog.SignalID,
        Max(LogTimeStamp) as LogTime
    FROM 
        [CRV_SignalLog]
        inner Join [CRV_SymbolSignals]
            on CRV_SignalLog.SignalID = CRV_SymbolSignals.SignalID
        inner Join [CRV_Symbols]
            on CRV_SymbolSignals.SymbolID = CRV_Symbols.SymbolID
        inner Join [CRV_Rooms]
            on CRV_Symbols.RoomID = CRV_Rooms.RoomID
    where 
        AttributeID = 'Display_Power'
    Group By 
        RoomName, 
        CRV_SignalLog.SignalID
    ) LastEntry
    Inner Join CRV_SignalLog 
        on CRV_SignalLog.SignalID = LastEntry.SignalID 
        AND CRV_SignalLog.LogTimeStamp = LastEntry.LogTime
Order By 
    RoomName
```

I'm assuming that LogTimeStamp is on the CRV_SignalLog table.

As you are worried about whether the LogTimeStamp is unique enough, here is another example that uses a sub-query to get the DigitalValue and will ensure that you only get one:

```
SELECT
    RoomName,
    (SELECT TOP 1 
        DigitalValue
     FROM
        CRV_SignalLog dvLog
     WHERE
        dvLog.SignalID = LastEntry.SignalID
        AND dvLog.LogTimeStamp = LastEntry.LogTime
    ) DigitalValue,
    LastEntry.LogTime
From
    (SELECT 
        RoomName,
        CRV_SignalLog.SignalID,
        Max(LogTimeStamp) as LogTime
    FROM 
        [CRV_SignalLog]
        inner Join [CRV_SymbolSignals]
            on CRV_SignalLog.SignalID = CRV_SymbolSignals.SignalID
        inner Join [CRV_Symbols]
            on CRV_SymbolSignals.SymbolID = CRV_Symbols.SymbolID
        inner Join [CRV_Rooms]
            on CRV_Symbols.RoomID = CRV_Rooms.RoomID
    where 
        AttributeID = 'Display_Power'
    Group By 
        RoomName, 
        CRV_SignalLog.SignalID
    ) LastEntry
Order By 
    RoomName
```

Comment: That did it - thank you. And yes, LogTimeStamp is in the CRV_SignalLog table. And I think I see why my original setup didn't work. SignalID is not a unique field to the first table and therefore the matching entries.

So that makes me think I should have used the LogID field which is unique to the first table, in place of the SignalID field. But confusingly - it also doesn't work by itself.

My concern is that, while unlikely, the LogTimeStamp field is not guaranteed to be unique.  So I am trying to keep the joins based upon key fields.

Comment: I now see why LogID won't work.  In order to link it, it also has to be in the sub Select's 'Group By' list - thereby blowing up the sub Select query.  But I am still concerned that the LogTimeStamp field is not assured to be unique.

Comment: I've added another example that think might help.

Comment: Ok, I am really very confused about how to correct innocent typos by Martin that are confusing his reply for other readers.  It is simple table name errors CVR_ and SRV_ instead of the original CRV_ .  But my attempts to edit these minor typos were twice rejected as making no sense and harming readability when they would obviously improve readability.  They are simple character substitutions.

Comment: Thank you Martin, for the new solution.  Turns out my concerns were founded as your original query returns 103 rows and the new one returns 101. On closer inspection, I found two rooms with two entries and it is because they have the same LogTimeStamp.

Comment: Was a bit odd that your corrections got rejected. I have done them myself so hopefully they will stay this time. Hopefully I got them all.